# Can't pass java parameters in the same format as c# for WCF service

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf, soap

This is the scenario: I have a WCF service running, who communicates with this method, in C#:

```
 public bool ValidateUser(UserPass up)
    {
        initializeAttributes();
        IMembershipService Member = new AccountMembershipService();
        bool login = Member.ValidateUser(up.User, up.Pass);
        return login;
    }
```

The parameter are encapsulated in this class:

```
[DataContract]
public class UserPass
{
    string user = "";
    string pass = "";
    string email = "";

    [DataMember]
    public string User
    {
        get { return user; }
        set { user = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Pass
    {
        get { return pass; }
        set { pass = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to connect to the server via an Android application, now, my question is, how can I replicate the UserPass class in Java, so the ValidateUser method can receive its parameter in a way it can understands it.

for reference, this is the code where I'm obtaining the User and Password:

```
private void validateUser(String user, String pass)
{

    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IUserService/ValidateUser/";
    String METHOD_NAME = "ValidateUser";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/UserService.svc";

    AlertDialog popup;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty(user, pass);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    envelope.bodyOut = request;
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try
    {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //here's the exception!!
        Object response = envelope.getResponse();

        popup = createAlertDialog("Respuesta",response.toString(),"OK");
        popup.show();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        String exceptionStr=exception.toString();

        popup = createAlertDialog("Exception!!",exceptionStr,"OK"); 
        popup.show();
    }       
}
```

The exception it throws is xmlpullparserexception, which, according to my understanding, is because of a missmatch between the parameters of the request and the actual method.

Many thanks for reading my question, and many more for those who can answer it :)

EDIT:

I finnaly got how to compare the XMLs... now, this is what my SOAP is providing:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
    <ValidateUser xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
        <User i:type="d:string">someuser</User>
        <Pass i:type="d:string">somepass</Pass>
    <Email i:type="d:string"></Email>
    </ValidateUser>
</v:Body>
```

and this is what it SHOULD have made (retrieved from WCF Test Client application from Visual Studio 2010):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IUserService/ValidateUser</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <ValidateUser xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <up xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LiveAndesWCF" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:Email i:nil="true" />
        <d4p1:Pass>somepass</d4p1:Pass>
        <d4p1:User>someuser</d4p1:User>
      </up>
    </ValidateUser>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Now, I'm lost on how to code my soap code to have it generate a xml file like the latter one.

Many thanks again.

Comment: Clearly there are differences, but it'd be helpful to know what the service wants from the clients. Can you generate a WSDL from the WCF service?

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I gave up on this and instead changed to a REST based service that now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks suspect to me:

```
request.addProperty(user, pass);
```

As far as I can tell, `SoapObject` comes from the KSOAP2 library, and according to the docs, addProperty takes the name of the property and the value. To set user and pass, I would expect something more like this:

```
request.addProperty("user", user);
request.addProperty("pass", pass);
```

Currently, it looks like you're adding a single property named using the value of the `user` parameter. If the endpoint is expecting at least 2 arguments, then this could be the source of your mismatch.

Also, is the value "Email", from the `UserPass` wrapper class, optional? As I don't see it being set anywhere, and the wrapper class suggests it's required by the SOAP request

Comment: Thank you!!, I changed the line you mentioned to: request.addProperty("User", user);
request.addProperty("Pass", pass); request.addProperty("Email","");, unfortunately, the same exception is thrown in the same place :(

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to look at the xml created by the soap call? you can compare it to the xml created by a .net proxy. maybe this helps to find a solution.

here is how you can enable the logging of the soap calls:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx